# LSTM : Best approach for embedding phrases

Tags: time-series, classification, lstm, keras

I'm learning about LSTM for classifying an event sequence to determine if it required human intervention or if it's on its "normal" way What I have is a list of events with timestamps for each sequence, of the form :

```
Time => User logged in
Time => User edited his profile
Time => Documents requested to the user
Time => User uploaded new documents
Time => Documents requested to the user
Time => Documents requested to the user
Time => User uploaded new documents
[...]
```

Each event is codified, there are approximately 150 distinct event types, with some "unknown/uncodified" events popping up from time to time (when an agents intervenes in the process, she can leave a comment which then shows in this event log)

I read a bunch of article about machine learning, and I think i should build a LSTM with an embedding layer as the first layer, to come up with a representation of my events

What I can't really decide on is if I should train / feed this layer with individual words of my event log, or if I should consider each event type as an individual "word" and the full sequence as a "phrase" composed of those "words" ?

Subsequent question : how would this layer react to unknown/uncodified events ? should i disregard them ? would the former choice (word vs full sentences) impact this second question ?